# Window Always on top. How to create such one?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

So I try:

```
<html> 
<head>
</head> <body> 
<script>
window.onblur = function() {
   window.focus();
};
</script>
</body> </html>
```

With idea in my head for window to always stay on top... but it does not. Why? How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make a Javascript popup window always stay on top, because you can't force focus on it from within the script.

And thank goodness for that! This would become the #1 Internet annoyance within weeks.

Related: [If The Internet Was A Real Place - Chappelle's Show](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8U7HztvetQk)

Comment: Yep.. I see. So is there any way to do what I wanted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349837/how-to-put-opened-popups-into-array-and-make-them-all-on-top-each-time-new-one-is ?

Comment: @Kabumbus nope, I don't think so. But does it have to be popup windows? Why not use dialog windows inside the document, like jQuery UI dialog? http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/