# How to put opened popUps into array and make them all on top each time new one is created?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, popup

So to open popUps I use

```
<script>
openWin = function(name, width, height, left, top){
    left=left+1;
    top=top+1;
    var file='./'+name+'.flv?action=read';
    var settings='width='+width+',height='+height+',left='+left+',top='+top+',screenX='+left+',screenY='+top+'';
    //alert(file);
    //alert(settings);
    var win = window.open(file, name, settings);
}
      </script>
```

I wonder how to put popUps into array when opening new one and make all created popUps on top each time new one is created?

Comment: Did you ever think about using modal dialog layers in the same document without using pop up windows? Using Pop Up windows this day in age is bad practice because of pop up blockers and restrictions browsers now add to their security model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an empty array to store each window. After creating a new one loop through the array and call each window's `focus` method:

```
var openWin = (function ()
{
    var popups = [];
    return function (name, width, height, left, top)
    {
        ++left;
        ++top;
        var file = './' + name + '.flv?action=read';
        var settings = 'width=' + width  + ',height=' + height + ',left=' + left + ',top=' + top + ',screenX=' + left + ',screenY=' + top;
        popups.push(window.open(file, name, settings));
        for (var i = 0; i < popups.length; ++i)
            popups[i].focus();
    }
})();
```

You may want to put everything inside a closure, so the array won't be exposed.

Comment: hM... i try '<script>
var windows = [];
openWin = function(name, width, height, left, top){
 left=left+1;
 top=top+1;
 var file='./'+name+'.flv?action=read';
 var settings='width='+width+',height='+height+',left='+left+',top='+top+',screenX='+left+',screenY='+top+'';
     windows.push(window.open(file, name, settings));
  
        for (var i = 0; i < windows.length(); ++i)
            windows[i].focus();

}
</script>' but it does not work..

Comment: Just tried exactly your way: '<script>
var openWin = (function () {
    var windows = []; return function(name, width, height, left, top){
 left=left+1;
 top=top+1;
 var file='./'+name+'.flv?action=read';
 var settings='width='+width+',height='+height+',left='+left+',top='+top+',screenX='+left+',screenY='+top+'';
     windows.push(window.open(file, name, settings));
  
        for (var i = 0; i < windows.length(); ++i)
            windows[i].focus();

}})();
</script>' it still opens windows but does not pop them up=(

Comment: Jenerally looking at debugger (chrome) I see it gives 'Uncaught TypeError: Property 'length' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
CloudObserverIndex.html:30Uncaught TypeError: Property 'length' of object [object DOMWindow],[object DOMWindow] is not a function'

Comment: So just I just got rid of windows => wins and used wins.length instead of windows.length()

Comment: Sorry it's my fault. I haven't used JS in a while I thought length was a method. Anyway I tested it and it works (http://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~ewie/) at least with FireFox.